# change back arrow image in Actionbar with appcompat-v7

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an `Actionbar` from `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`. It has hamburger image with animation to back arrow, I want to change back arrow from <- to ->. how can I do this in Android Studio?

I read somewhere to change it with `setHomeAsUpIndicator()` method, but it change hamburger button and it has no animation to back arrow.

Comment: An image visualization will,be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least half a dozen ways to do this, but probably the simplest and shortest is to use reflection to grab the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`'s `Drawable`, and flip its direction.

This example wraps that functionality in a subclass, and should work no matter your `ActionBar`/`Activity` setup (provided the original class worked there in the first place).

```
public class FlippedDrawerToggle extends ActionBarDrawerToggle {
    public FlippedDrawerToggle(Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout,
        int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes) {

        this(activity, drawerLayout, null,
            openDrawerContentDescRes, closeDrawerContentDescRes);
    }

    public FlippedDrawerToggle(Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout,
        Toolbar toolbar, int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes) {

        super(activity, drawerLayout, toolbar,
             openDrawerContentDescRes, closeDrawerContentDescRes);

        try {
            Field sliderField = ActionBarDrawerToggle.class.getDeclaredField("mSlider");
            sliderField.setAccessible(true);
            DrawerArrowDrawable arrow = (DrawerArrowDrawable) sliderField.get(this);
            arrow.setDirection(DrawerArrowDrawable.ARROW_DIRECTION_RIGHT);
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            // Fail silently
        }
    }
}
```

This will only change the direction of the toggle's image. If you actually want the whole `ActionBar`/`Toolbar` to be flipped, you should instead change the layout's direction accordingly.

Comment: No problem. In case you didn't notice, I changed a few things in the code since I originally posted it. I had forgotten about the constructor that takes a `Toolbar`, and I was using a direction constant that's only available in 19+. I think it should be good to go now. Cheers!

Comment: another question: Do you know how to set `layoutdirection` to `RTL` for API level below 17? because right now hamburger image is on the left of actionbar

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, before API 17, you have to handle that stuff yourself. If you use a `Toolbar` instead of the decor-provided `ActionBar`, it's a little easier, 'cause a `Toolbar` is just a regular `ViewGroup` you can setup in XML. In that case, though, `ActionBarDrawerToggle` isn't what you want, since it'll stick to the left side. However, using an `ImageButton` and a `DrawerArrowDrawable`, you can create a custom toggle that looks and acts the same, and you can place it on the right side of your `Toolbar`. In the `DrawerLayout`, just set the `layout_gravity` of your drawer to `right`.

Comment: you mean in this case i used, I have no option?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but AFAIK, before API 17, there's no way mirror a layout for RTL with just a simple attribute, like `layoutDirection`. You'll have to use a custom layout and toggle, but it's not too difficult if you use a `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//Find the action bar for customizations
    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    assert ab != null;

    //Make the action bar display an up arrow and set its drawable and color
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    final Drawable upArrow = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
            getResources(),
            R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha, //this is the <- arrow from android resources. Change this to the thing you want.
            null);
    assert upArrow != null;
    upArrow.setColorFilter(
            ContextCompat.getColor(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    R.color.white // change this to the color you want (or remove the setColorFilter call)
            ),
            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

Comment: I said it in my question that I tested `setHomeAsUpIndicator`. but it removes animation and it just change the hamburger image

Answer (score 0):

Add this condition between  `mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle...` and `mDrawerToggle.syncState();` like this :

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


if (getResources().getConfiguration().getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL)
{
      toolbar.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
}


mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```